# How can I make a relationship betwen: User, Medic, Patient, Consultation, Prescription on RoR 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design, devise, relationship

I have a difficulties for make the relationships in a small project for medical office, I'm using Devise for User login, the logic for the relationship that have sense to me is this:

1. Registered user can create a profile 'Medic'
2. User can create a new 'patient' (which should be related to current devise User => 'Medic')
3. New patient have a new 'consultation'
4. And the consultation have a 'prescription'

so, I set my models there by:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :medic
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end

class Medic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :medic
  has_many :consultum
end

class Consultum < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient
  has_one :prescription
end

class Prescription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :consultum
end
```

For the scaffolds I run:

```
rails g scaffold Patient name last_name email phone references:medic
```

and so on...

I feel that I am missing something, ¿How can I set the relationship properly without no troubles in the future?, ¿is there any other way (best practice)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `has_many` relationships should be named in plural e.g. `has_many :patients` or `has_many : consulta`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need a separate `Medic` model associated to `User`.

If your `user` is going to be a `medic` anyway, why not ditch the `medic` model and just use `User`? If you'd prefer to call your `User` model `Medic`, even better. You'll have to change some references in your app:

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :medics

#app/models/medic.rb
class Medic < ActiveRecord::Base
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

   has_one :profile
   before_create :build_profile
end
```

This gives you access to `current_medic`.

If you need a *profile* for your medic, that's different:

```
#app/models/profile.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :medic
end
```

This will allow you to call `@medic.profile` - calling information you'd rather keep out of your "users" model.

Although this might seem off-topic, it will help your associations profusely.

---

```
#app/models/medic.rb
class Medic < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :consultations
   has_many :patients, through: :consultations
end

#app/model/consultation.rb
class Consultation < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :patient
   belongs_to :medic
   has_one :prescription
end

#app/models/patient.rb
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :consultations
   has_many :medics, through: :consultations
end

#app/models/prescription.rb
class Prescription < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :consultation
end
```

-

To check:

> Registered user can create a profile 'Medic'

Just use `current_medic`

Your patients don't need to be users, just add them manually. You'll save yourself massive headaches by just using `Medic` instead of `User`.

My implementation also gives a medic a profile:

```
current_medic.profile
```

> Medic can create a new 'patient'

```
current_medic.patients.new ...
```

> Patient have a new 'consultation'

```
@consultation = @patient.consultation.new ...
@consultation.medic = Medic.find ...
```

> Consultation have a 'prescription'

```
@consultation.prescription
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you did the relationships just fine, but if you really like to read some good docs on rails relationship read this:

http://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/top-10-mistakes-that-rails-programmers-make

one of the the important things is the fields in this models and the types, if you choose it correctly it will be more easy to keep your code efficient.

Answer (score 0):

`has_many` requires plural names. In addition I believe:

```
class Consultum < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient
  has_many :prescriptions
end
```